# Error while forcing index in cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using version 2.0.1 of Neo4j.

I have a label named as **prod** and a property as **id**.

My doubt is as follows:

The following query return results very fast:

```
profile match (p:PROD) where p.id="111" return p;

SchemaIndex(identifier="n", _db_hits=0, _rows=2, label="Prod", query="Literal(111)", property="id")
```

But when i use a list using **IN** and force **index usage**:

```
profile match (p:PROD) USING INDEX p:PROD(id) where p.id IN ["111","222"] return p;
```

It shows the following error:

```
IndexHintException: Cannot use index hint in this context. The label and property comparison must be specified on a non-optional node
Label: `prod`
Property name: `id`
```

Why can't i use the USE INDEX method to specify the index.? What am i doing wrong? How should i correct it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WHERE` conditions using the `IN` operator do not use indexes in Neo4j 2.0.x. Please upgrade to 2.1.3 which supports this operation.